# Jenkins seed job that executes only DSL scripts modified since the last run?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have several source code repositories containing various bits of code built by Jenkins, with a one-to-one mapping between Jenkins jobs and source repositories. Separate from these, I have a *single* repository containing Job DSL scripts for creating/updating the Jenkins jobs that build the other repos. The situation looks something like this:

[image]

I had hoped to find a way to store the Job DSL scripts inside the individual source repositories, right alongside the code, and have a single seed job that would be triggered by push notifications to *any* of the other repositories. Unfortunately, it appears that this is currently not well supported (see the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41602602/99127)). Given that, it seems simplest for now to just leave all the DSLs in a single, separate repository, and let push notifications to that repository trigger reprocessing of the groovy scripts. And it all works fine, more-or-less.

That said, I'm slightly concerned that the seed job—when triggered—re-runs *all* of the DSL scripts, rather than only those that have actually changed. (I'm honestly not sure whether this is a 'problem', per se, I just worry that it could lead to surprising behavior later on.)

Is there some way I can restructure the seed job so that it only re-runs scripts modified by the commit that triggered the build? Or... is this not worth worrying about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Job DSL will only update a job if the generated config changes. It compares the generated XML with the existing config to see if an update is necessary. See [JenkinsJobManagement.java](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/job-dsl-1.57/job-dsl-plugin/src/main/groovy/javaposse/jobdsl/plugin/JenkinsJobManagement.java#L477-L490). So if you do not change jobs manually or run malicious plugins that modify the job's config in the background, there should be no problem when re-running scripts.

And Job DSL reuses the Groovy script engine when running multiple scripts, so the performance impact should be low. See [DslScriptLoader.groovy](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/job-dsl-1.57/job-dsl-core/src/main/groovy/javaposse/jobdsl/dsl/DslScriptLoader.groovy#L45-L53).

So if your scripts have no side effects (e.g. making REST calls or modifying the file system), then it should be no problem to re-run scripts even if unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that I need not worry about re-running unmodified DSL scripts—and especially for providing a source code link to prove it.

Comment: Hi, I know its old post but what if I want to manually check difference? 
trivia: there is issue with having "build with parameters", they are not displayed in Jenkins UI correctly if changed unless you run pipeline.
See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44422691/how-to-force-jenkins-to-reload-a-jenkinsfile/70083512#70083512