# Which Jenkins Command to Get the List of Changed Files

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-cli

In a Jenkins build I see a list of changed files:

[image]

So which command Jenkins uses to get this list (I am using git for repository version control).

Answer (score 17):

You can use the [changeSets](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/scm/ChangeLogSet.html) property of the *currentBuild* global variable to get information relating to the detected changes of the current build.

e.g.

```java
// returns a list of changed files
@NonCPS
String getChangedFilesList() {
    changedFiles = []
    for (changeLogSet in currentBuild.changeSets) {
        for (entry in changeLogSet.getItems()) { // for each commit in the detected changes
            for (file in entry.getAffectedFiles()) {
                changedFiles.add(file.getPath()) // add changed file to list
            }
        }
    }
    return changedFiles
}
```

Comment: which language that you are using? Could I write this in Linux Bash script?

Comment: This is groovy code which is typically used in a [scripted Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline).  It can also be executed using the 'execute Groovy script' step in the Build section of a Freestyle job.

Comment: @MenX it is better to use `Groovy script` if you have to run that code on win and linux.

Comment: Thanks for the code, it works well, but the return type should be `List<String>`, not `String`, and since Jenkins/Groovy is silently converting to String, it took me a while to spot what was wrong.

Comment: How can I get this list of files (changedFiles) to display or into another script in a declaritive pipeline?

Comment: can currentBuild also return the git hash?

Comment: @red888 SCM-specific variables such as GIT_COMMIT are not automatically defined as environment variables; rather you can use the return value of the checkout step.

Comment: Saved me a day. Works flawlessly.

Answer (score 5):

Possibly one of the two possible commands listed in "[How to list all the files in a commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/424142/6309)":

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r <commit-ish>
```

Note that the [Jenkins Git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-Environmentvariables) does expose that commit as an environment variable: `GIT_COMMIT`

Comment: if build has multiple commits? how to go for that case?

Comment: @user_9090 `git diff-tree` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree) can take *two* <treeish>: simply diff between the older and newest commit displayed in Jenkins build list of commits.

Comment: in case of Jenkins first build, we will not have GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT, How can we approach for this?

Comment: @user_9090 then you need to fallback to a convention, like <commit-ish>~1: the parent commit. That is an approximation though. Or you could differ against the empty tree (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9766506/6309) to get *all* files created so far.

Comment: is there a way in which we can calculate total commits in a Jenkins build?

Comment: @user_9090 if you have th GIT_PROVIOUS_COMMIT, then yes, you can count commits between that reference and GIT_COMMIT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31998123/6309

Comment: yes, but for Jenkins first build it (GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT) won't be available. Is there any way for the first build.

Comment: @user_9090 Sure: you can get first to the first commit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5189296/6309. Then you can count between that first commit and your current "first" Jenkins Git commit.

Comment: this is giving me the first commit of the repo

Comment: @user_9090 Yes, as an approximation, since the Jenkins first build has no previous build.

Comment: so, for the jenkins first build we cannot get the files that are being changed

Comment: @user_9090 You can, but only by listing said file since the first commit of the repo.

Comment: for that I have to use this command only "git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD" , or any other way

Comment: @user_9090 yes, that command is the recommended way, except you might replace HEAD by GIT_COMMIT, to reference the commit used by Jenkins for its (first) build.