# Is it possible to get the Git hash outside of the pipeline{} directive?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm using Jenkins multibranch pipelines.

I want to get the Git hash *before* the pipeline even starts and wondering if the data is available in some system class or variable. I don't want to shell out to the `git` command nor have to wait till the `checkout scm` step is executed and then read properties of that object.

Perhaps this is impossible, but it does seem like I can get a list of changed files before the check step and pipeline directive with `currentBuild.changeSets` like this: [Which Jenkins Command to Get the List of Changed Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54175878/which-jenkins-command-to-get-the-list-of-changed-files).

What other secrets does `currentBuild` greedily hide from me? Does it have a method that could retrieve the current git hash of the branch- again *before* the checkout step the runs inside the pipeline?

Also, to add why I think this is possible, I see this console output whenever a multibranch job starts:

```
Started by user me
Obtained mydir/Jenkinsfile from <FULL GIT HASH OF COMMIT>
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
.....
```

So clearly Jenkins gets the hash of the commit immediately. I'm hoping it's possible to retrieve in code.

Answer (score 1):

See `http://<Your Jenkins>/env-vars.html/`:

> The following variables are available to shell scripts
> ...
> **GIT_COMMIT**
> The commit hash being checked out.
> ...

#### UPDATE

See also:

- [Jenkins Git environment variables list: A working shell script example](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Complete-Jenkins-Git-environment-variables-list-for-batch-jobs-and-shell-script-builds)
- [Jenkins Set Environment Variables](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-belowJenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables)

> | Environment Variable | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | GIT_COMMIT | For Git-based projects, this variable contains the Git hash of the commit checked out for the build (like ce9a3c1404e8c91be604088670e93434c4253f03) (all the GIT_* variables require git plugin) |

I'm using it in a declarative Jenkinsfile of a Multibranch Pipeline project:

```groovy
        stage('Set build description') {
            steps {
                buildDescription "Commit: ${GIT_COMMIT}"
            }
        }
```

and the result is:

[image]

Comment: GIT_COMMIT has never existed for multibranch pipelines so not sure where you are seeing this is available or if you have some 3rd party plugin. If I dump the `env` var before the pipeline{} directive via `env.getEnvironment()` or even inside the pipeline directive with sh step doing `printenv` I see no GIT_* variables set.

Comment: @red888 As mentioned, I see this when opening the page `env-vars.html` on my Jenkins. See also the update to my answer. And I'm actually using this in a Multibranch Pipeline project's (declarative) Jenkinsfile.

Comment: Im sorry but those env vars do not exist for multibranch pipelines out of the box you must have a specific scm plugin or something. You can google this and find people trying to get the git hash like I am who are in the same boat

Comment: @red888 See the heading of the first paragraph of the linked article: _Jenkins Git plugin environment variables list_.

Comment: This only works if a stage has ran where a node was used and scm checkout happened.  I have an 'init' stage with 'agent none' where this variable doesn't exist yet.  Once I added an agent block for that init stage it worked (even though I don't have anything in that stage that requires an agent).  Would be nice if that wasn't a requirement, but it is...